# Android MediaScanner finalize()

Tags: android, finalize, android-mediascanner

In Gingerbread 2.3.4, there are times that the ***unmounting of SDCard fails***. When I checked the log, **mediaserver** is still accessing some files in the sdcard and even **vold** throw **SIGKILL** at mediaserver, mediaserver will just turn into a *zombie process* and unmount operation would still fail.

I think the cause of failure is that the **MediaScanner** is still holding references to the objects which holds reference to the file in the sdcard. **MediaScanner** is used in **MediaProvider** to ***extract album art*** from a media file. However, even if the extracting album art operation is already finished, ***MediaScanner is still not released by the Garbage Collector***. And when unmount operation is done on this state, unmount operation will surely fail. It will not fail when MediaScanner is released before unmounting the SDCard.

What I did is I added a **release()** function in the **MediaScanner** class which will be called by **MediaProvider** once it is done with extracting album art. Inside release() function, it will call **native_finalize()**. After the changes, I am able to unmount the SDCard successfully.

In the original source code of **MediaScanner**, the objects referenced by **MediaScanner** are released inside the **finalize()** function.

Is anyone of you experienced the same problem with mine? Is there other workaround aside from what I have mentioned above?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
artsylar